# how to change color by inline css

Tags: html, css

I have a div, in css there is blue color for that div. Now I need to change that color dynamically. I store color in database  and want to use database hexadecimal color code in that div.

How to change the default blue color?

I can fetch color from database. But can't use inline css to apply color came from database.. Lets suppose from database color will come like `#3B5323`.

Comment: Are you asking how the inline CSS looks like, or how to fetch/insert your hex code?

Comment: What programming language do you use? Have you already tried something?

Comment: Do you want to use just CSS to change color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to show you exactly how to do it without any code but here is an example:

```
$colour_from_db = '#3B5323'; // this would actually be a variable from the db
<div style="color:<?=$colour_from_db?>;">

</div>
```

**Note**: I'm assuming you mean the text colour, hence I have added `style="color:`, however if you are wanting to change the background colour, you would apply the CSS as normal, `style="background-color:`

Where `$colour_from_db` is the variable that stores the hexadecimal colour code

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using PHP and you mean the background color:

```
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $colorFromQuery ?>;"></div>
```

Comment: ups... you're right. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment I am answering your question. when do you want to change div color? you can do something like this.

```
<div align="center" class="<%=styleClass %>"></div>
```

Use jquery to set the colour to `styleClass`.

Comment: There's no need to use jQuery or Javascript at all to accomplish this task

Comment: @DannyHearnah first of all the question is unclear.what if div colour has to be changed on some event rather than straight away?